# Defining a stream as private class variable seems working under Linux but not under Windows Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, stream, private

I've already found several topics on this forum discussing about the not allowed copy of stream objects, but I'm not sure (at least I don't think so) this is my case.

I want to define a stream as private variable of a given class. I've already done this in the past for an application written under Ubuntu, something like

```
class of_driving{
public:
    of_driving();
    ~of_driving();

    // ... Some public stuff ...

private:
    // ... Some private stuff ...
    std::ofstream J_f;
};
```

and this worked easily.
Now, I'm trying to do basically the same thing for another application, but I'm working on Visual Studio under Windows:

```
class FTSensor{

public:
    FTSensor();
    ~FTSensor();
private:
    std::stringstream ftMeasurementSS;
};
```

However, when I build the solution I got the following error:

> Errore    2   error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sstream  724

Can anyone explain me this behaviour? I highlighted that I worked on different OS just because it seems to be the only difference so far for me, but I expect also that the reason could be of different nature.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of MSVS are you using?

Comment: Difference in OS's is irrelevant. What is important is the compiler, in your case, for Windows VC++, and under Ubuntu gcc I would say, although you don't specify. There are always multiple compilers under the same platform, so listing the platform doesn't help much.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to copy the stream. Provide a **complete, reproducible example**, minimal.

Comment: I'm using VS 2013, but the selected platform tool set in the Property panel is set to Visual Studio 2010. Unfortunately, I can't remember the gcc version in Ubuntu, but in that case I set the flag -std=c++11 in the CMakeLists.txt, and I don't know how to check if it is set on VS  as well

Comment: Both of the version have lacking C++11 support with MSVS 2010 having laughable support.  Most likely you either need to use the MSVS 2013 tool set or update and use MSVS 2015.

Comment: @MarcoFerro [See this](http://rextester.com/HGXFJA87077).  This is a speculation of what you are trying to do (either explicitly or implicitly), and the compiler stops it from happening.  The issue is that you are probably not aware of the "secret places" that copying may occur, such as passing or returning by value.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  It is hard to produce a complete and reproducible example, because the error is raised just after the definition of the stream in the class. I'm not using it anywhere yet. Moreover, if the problem is about copying as you say, I do not understand why the first solution works.

Comment: Ok I got what you say, and probably I think I found the source of the error.
In the main function, I defined an instance of the class FTSensor, and then I passed this instance to boost::bind to create a thread. In that case, I basically passed the whole class by value. Commenting that boost::bind does not arise the error. I wrote this as answer to the post. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cheersandhth.-Alf and @PaulMcKenzie pointed out, the reason of the error lies in a copying mechanism. 
In fact, in my `main.cpp` I wrote

```
int main(){

FTSensor fts;
tg.create_thread(boost::bind(&FTSensor::threadCallback,fts));
tg.join_all();

}
```

where the instance `fts` of the whole class `FTSensor` is passed by value in the `boost::bind` method, arising the error above. Correcting the line in

```
tg.create_thread(boost::bind(&FTSensor::threadCallback,&fts));
```

results in a successfull build. 
Thank you for your fast support.